# How to send a Twitter request from Python

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

So i've been using www.hurl.it to send some twitter app authenticated GET requests. Like this..

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=userfoo
```

Then I put in my user keys and tokens and it sends this request

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&oauth_nonce=***********&screen_name=userfoo&oauth_timestamp=**********&oauth_signature=***********=&oauth_token=**********&oauth_consumer_key=**********&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0
```

So I know a little basic python and I would like to know the most simple way of doing this in python without any library. I just want to send a one time request. Something like this.

```
>>>import requests
>>>r = requests.get("http://example.com/foo/bar")
>>>print r.status_code
>>>print r.headers
>>>print r.content
```

So the GET request that needs to be sent have "oauth_nonce", "oauth_signature" and "oauth_timestamp" values. How do I go about getting these values? I would like to do it without any additional libraries. If it is not possible to do it without additional libraries let me know of another way. But I don't know to much about python so it will have to be explained very well.

Thanks

Comment: "How do I go about getting these values?" Are you trying to get values for these, or are you trying to use them to send to another URL?

Comment: I need the value for the get request, for the current url. I need to get the values before I send the request. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used the Tweepy library instead. It seems to be working fine.